# Open Mapping Theorem: counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

The Open Mapping Theorem says that a linear continuous
surjection between Banach spaces is an open mapping.
I am writing some lecture notes on the Open Mapping Theorem.
I guess it would be nice to have some counterexamples.
After all, how can you appreciate it's meaning without a
nice counterexample showing how the conclusion could fail
and why the conclusion is not obvious at all.

Let $\ell^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^\infty$ be the set of sequences
$(a_1, a_2, \dotsc)$, such that $\sum |a_j| < \infty$.
If we consider the $\ell^1$ norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ and
the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_s$, then,
$(\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_1)$ is complete,
while $(\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_s)$ is not complete.

In this case, the identity
$$
  \begin{array}{rrcl}
    \mathrm{id}:& (\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_1)& \to &(\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_s)
    \\
                & x & \mapsto & x
  \end{array}
$$
is a continuous bijection but it is not open.

I want a counterexample in the opposite direction.
That is, I want a linear continuous bijection
$T: E \to F$ between normed spaces $E$ and $F$
such that $F$ is Banach but $T$ is not open.
This is equivalent to finding a vector space
$E$ with non-equivalent norms $\|\cdot\|_c$ and $\|\cdot\|_n$,
such that $E$ is complete when considered the norm $\|\cdot\|_c$,
and such that
$$
  \|\cdot\|_c
  \leq
  \|\cdot\|_n.
$$
The Open Mapping Theorem implies that $\|\cdot\|_n$ is
not complete.

So, is anyone aware of such a counterexample?

Comment: @AndréCaldas is there any hint why l1 with the sup norm is not complete?

Comment: @Charles: take any sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\sum a_n = \infty$ and $a_n \rightarrow 0$. The sequence $A_n = (a_1, \dotsc a_n, 0, 0, 0, \dotsc)$ belongs to $\ell^1$. The sequence $A_n$ is Cauchy with the supremum norm since $a_n \rightarrow 0$. It actually converges to $(a_1, a_2, \dotsc) \in \ell^\infty \setminus \ell^1$. In fact, the closure of $\ell^1$ is $c_0 \subset \ell^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is given [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44716/counterexample-for-the-open-mapping-theorem).

Thanks to David Mitra who pointed out this in a comment.