# Open maping theorem. Completeness assumption are important

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The open maping theorem between banach spaces says.

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear,continuous and surjective map between the banach spaces $X,Y$ then $T$ is an open map.

I need examples to show that the completeness assumption are important even in the presence of completeness of the other space. Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44716/counterexample-for-the-open-mapping-theorem) mathoverflow post for the harder part. Also, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291671/open-mapping-theorem-counterexample) post here.