# Example of bijection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Is possible to find an example of a Banach space $E_1$ and normed vector space $E_2$ and bijection operator $A \in \mathcal{L} (E_1, E_2)$, that $A^{-1}$ will not be bounded?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291671/open-mapping-theorem-counterexample).

Comment: @DavidMitra That one goes in the other direction, though. Here the domain is assumed complete, not the codomain.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY The question contains the standard example.

Answer (score 0):

You can even make $E_1$ a Hilbert space, say $\ell^2$. Define another norm on $\ell^2$ by 
$$\|x\|_*^2 = \sum_n \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2}$$ 
The identity map $\operatorname{id}:\ell^2\to (\ell^2,\|\cdot\|_*)$ is bounded, but its inverse is not. Indeed, for the standard basis vectors we have  $\|e_n\|_*= 1/n$ while $\|e_n\|_{\ell^2}=1$.